# Can't make API call react-create-app with node error 403

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express

This is the fetch

```
let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/signup',{
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        body : JSON.stringify(data)
    })
```

Here's my routes in server-side

```
const express = require('express');

const userController = require('../controllers/user');
const auth = require('../middlewares/auth');

const api = express.Router();

api.post('/signup', auth ,userController);

module.exports = api;
```

My User controller

```
    const User = require('../models/user');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const services = require('../services')

function signUp(req,res){
    const user = new User({
        name : req.body.name,
        email : req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password
    })

    user.save((err)=>{
        if(err) return console.log(err);

        res.status(201).send({token: service.createToken})
    })
}

module.exports = signUp
```

The server is running fine at localhost:3001

I tried to use proxy in package.json but didn't work either

Comment: Write down the error trace you are recieving in order to help you.

Comment: are you having a cors issue?

Comment: Are you using the [proxy](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development) config? If yes, you can remove `http://localhsot:3001` and fetch only with `fetch(/api/signup, { ... })`

Comment: I'm not using the proxy config

Comment: I,' just recieving (https://localhost:3001/api/signup) 403 (Forbbiden)

Comment: could you show us your signup route ? on server-side

Comment: Look at the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your auth middleware on the `/signup` route, so you are requiring an authenticated user to signUp, just remove it for this route :

```
api.post('/signup', userController);
```